# Unable to login to admin interface in Django Nonrel

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

As [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108214/django-nonrel-cant-log-into-admin-panel-on-development-server) people, I can't login to Django (Nonrel) admin interface, and the solution other users have given don't work in my situation. I'm running Python 2.7 and Google App Engine 1.6.0.

Let's see. I have this in my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'home.html'}),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And this in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'mediagenerator.middleware.MediaMiddleware',
    # This loads the index definitions, so it has to come first
    'autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',
    # Media middleware has to come first

    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'djangotoolbox',
    'autoload',
    'dbindexer',
    'mediagenerator',

    # djangoappengine should come last, so it can override a few manage.py commands
    'djangoappengine',
)
```

I created a superuser after uncommenting 'django.contrib.admin' but it doesn't work. I created another superuser manually (via python manage.py createsuperuser), which doesn't work either. However, the weird part is that those superusers are available:

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all()
[<User: robert>, <User: john>]
>>> User.objects.all()[0].is_staff
True
>>> User.objects.all()[0].is_superuser
True
```

And yet, I can't login.

I don't know if it's related, but when a run python manage.py runserver, I get the following exception:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 55568)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2438, in __init__
    BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 641, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 694, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Any suggestions?

By the way, I have created superusers without the server running, as David Poblador suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751434/cant-login-to-django-admin-interface).

**UPDATE**: I tried to deploy (python manage.py deploy), but it happens exactly the same. I can't login with any superuser, although other than that, there are no errors.

**UPDATE 2**: I read a thread that suggested looking at /_ah/admin, but I'm not sure what to do there. I have `auth_user`, `_AhAdminXsrfToken`, `django_session` and a couple of 'tables' in the 'Entity Kind' field in Datastore Viewer. When I select auth_user, I get the following message "Datastore contains no entities of kind "auth_user" in the Empty namespace".

**UPDATE 3**: Alright, now I'm officially confused. I created another project using [django-testapp](https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/django-testapp) adding only `middleware_classes`, `autodiscover` and `django.contrib.admin` to enable the admin interface. It loads the 'it works' page but I get that exception. It happens the same when I load `localhost/admin`. Again, after querying `User.objects.all()`, I get the correct list of superusers, but they don't work in the login page.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I partially solved the problem.

I downloaded again each file from [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine), however, this time I used the clone link instead of the direct zip files (the ones that have /get/tip.zip). I modified settings.py and urls.py to enable administration.

After that, I was able to log in to the admin interface. Nonetheless, when I start a request (any request), I get the same Exception described above. That remains to be solved.